# Media library with variable availability

Tags: windows-media-center, video-streaming, media-player

I have a collection of movies:

A laptop might have a subset of these internally; the complete library might be available on a connected external disk.  Various subsets might be available in the network, both as files and/or as Windows streaming.

How can I see my total library? what is currently available? And how can I easily launch available items?

I am mostly thinking about Windows clients, though I also have Android

Answer (score 1):

Using Zoom Player, you can specify multiple drives/folders into a virtual category that combines them all.  Sources not available (drives disconnected or non-mapped network drives) will not be listed.